# Where is "Reveal in Finder" in Xcode 3.2.3?

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

I have updated to Xcode 3.2.3 to develop for the iPad and iPhone 4, but I can't find the "Reveal in Finder" button to locate the .app file.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Products node (between Frameworks and Targets) instead of the Executables node.
Then popup the menu on the .app file there.